# how to draw datatable columns values

Tags: jquery, datatables

In `datatable` `ajax` loading I want to draw value of one column based on another so following is the code :

```
 var oTable = $('#tblOrderList').on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                $(this).dataTable().api().clear();
                settings.iDraw = 0;
                $(this).dataTable().api().draw();
                data.CustomerNo = phoneNo;
            }).DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '/PBF/GetOrderList',
                    "type": "post",
                    "datatype": "json",
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "OrderNo", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Date", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                    {
                        "data": "OrderNo", "width": "2px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateInvoiceModal" class="updateInvoice" data-id=' + data + '><i style="font-size:medium;padding:20px" class="icon-pencil-square-o"></i></a>';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "info": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bDestroy": true
            });
```

I want to write sixth column value based on fifth column data ,fifth column gets values **delivered or undelivered**

```
{
      "data": "OrderNo", "width": "2px", "render": function (data) {
      if(Status==delivered)
      {
         return '-';
      }
      else
      {
         return 'something';
      }
}
```

Comment: Set a custom render function using `columnDefs`. The function will take several arguments and one of them is row data. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: can you please help me with coding it because i am new at using datatables i found this code online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like:

```
 var oTable = $('#tblOrderList').on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                $(this).dataTable().api().clear();
                settings.iDraw = 0;
                $(this).dataTable().api().draw();
                data.CustomerNo = phoneNo;
            }).DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '/PBF/GetOrderList',
                    "type": "post",
                    "datatype": "json",
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "OrderNo", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Date", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                    {
                        "data": null, "width": "2px", "render": function (data) {
                            if(data.Status == "delivered"){
                                return '-';
                            }else{
                                return data.OrderNo;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "info": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bDestroy": true
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for this which you have done, but you've omitted the parameters. The `full` parameter represents the entire row of data, so you can access any column using the index eg `full[4]`. Note that this is zero-based so the 5th column is the 4th index.

```
"columns": [
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "OrderNo", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Date", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Status", "autoWidth": true },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                             if(full[4] == 'delivered'){
                                return '-';
                             }else{
                                return 'something';
                             }
                         }
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: Can you paste the json server response?

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 83,
      "Name": "John Smith",
      "Phone": "123456789",
      "OrderNo": "SOB123456",
      "Date": "2017-06-02",
      "Status": "Delivered"
    }
  ]
}